# Not able to pass value from one view controller to another on storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a problem I am calling `WSLogin` class from my `Loginviewcontroller`. and it successfully return my *sessionId* of User. then I am storing this *sessionId* into string and sending this value to `Searchviewcontroller` but not successfully submit value to `Searchviewcontroller`.

when I succesfully login then I move to `Searchviewcontroller` through tab-bar controller. I generate `NSLog` in `searchviewcontroller` to check the value of session when I click on `searchtabbar` after successfully login then on `NSLog session id = null` return to me kindly tell me how I can fix this problem?

This is the code

```
// LoginViewController.m file 
-(IBAction)Login:(id)sender
{
    wsobject = [[WSLogin alloc] init];
    sessId = wsobject.sessionId;
    NSLog(@"sessionidd = %@",sessId);
// it successfully return session id 
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    SearchViewController *afc = (SearchViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
    afc.sessionId = sessId;
// i have create sessionId property in SearchViewController 
}
// SearhViewController.m file 
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"sessionId = %@",sessionId);
//printing sessionId value but getting Null here when click on Searhtabbar
}
```

Comment: Can you post your property declarations for both the LoginViewController and SearchViewController?

Comment: yes i have declare property for both strings for sessId in loginviewcontroller and for sessionId in searchviewcontroller

Comment: @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *sessId;

Comment: @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *sessionId;

Comment: While creating the application,u have missed a small thing in appdelegate,thats why you are not getting the value in navigation Try to find it out by yourself,its quiet simple

Comment: Are you using ARC? If you are I'd suggest changing your property declarations to:
 "@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *sessId;"
 "@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *sessionId;"
And depending on which version of Xcode your are using you might have to synthesize these properties. Also you'll have to call them by the self pointer "self.sessId = wsobject.sessionId;"

Comment: its not working the problem is when click on tabbarcontroller the value return null

Answer (score 0):

I'm asuming that you've already perpare segues for the same and in identity inspector gave it a name, say "goToNextView". Now put the following code where you're jumping to next view controller

```
-(IBAction)methodName:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToNextView" sender:self];
}
```

Then in your code modify prepare for segue delegate method like this

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
            if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goToNextView"]) {
         DestinatonViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController
        // set the properties value you want for destination View Controller
                controller.propertyName = yourValue;
```

Hope this will help..